# ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(applica Uncaught error from thread, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem

Tags: java, playframework

I am working on an Android app and I am trying to get the login function to work, when a user logins a request should be sent to the backend for it to authenticate the information provided and send back a response, looking at the stack trace the code goes through most of the authentication for the account that it checks the user name, password, and account status but the code always crashes and I get this error and it shuts down the SBT that was running.

[image]

[image: tack trace of error]

[image].

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead of that, copy paste the text using the [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Based on the error you got, I would guess that the problem is the JVM version you are using to run the project. [Play 2.6.5 does not work with Java 9](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7879). If that is not the case, try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @GastónSchabas Thank you for the info I will into my JVM version and see if that fixes the problem.